# Vector CAPL Node multiple times execution in CANoe

Tags: capl, canoe

When setting 'multiple number of executions' under Testmodulelist->Options, how can I determine the current execution round in CAPL code?

This is related to Properties NumberOfExecutions, ExecutionMode etc. mentioned in the CANoe help.

Answer (score 1):

In the Test execution windows (bottom right) you have an indicator that says how many times the TM was repeated: e.g.

> 3 of 10 executions

Comment: ok, that's right. Problem is still to aquire these numbers somehow in the running CAPL code...